# undefined object when defined in Angular Unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm working through my test environment and am trying to get around an issue with a single user profile through `oidc-client` being undefined during unit testing.

I have tried making the `BeforeEach` methods `async` that has not helped, and I have also tried restructuring my `AuthService` as well.

This is the error that I am getting from the test components:

`ResourcesCardComponent > should create`

`Failed: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined`

**AuthService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserManager, User, WebStorageStateStore } from 'oidc-client';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { ConfigAssetLoaderService } from '../config-asset-loader.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private _userManager: UserManager;
  public _user: User;
  public isLoggedInSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this._user);
  isLoggedIn = this.isLoggedInSubject$.asObservable();

  constructor(private configService: ConfigAssetLoaderService) {
    const config = {};
    this.configService.loadConfiguration().subscribe(response => {
      config['authority'] = response.authority;
      config['client_id'] = response.client_id;
      config['redirect_uri'] = response.redirect_uri;
      config['scope'] = response.scope;
      config['response_type'] = response.response_type;
      config['loadUserInfo'] = response.loadUserInfo;
      config['userStore'] = new WebStorageStateStore({store: window.sessionStorage});
      config['metadata'] = {
        issuer: response.issuer,
        authorization_endpoint: response.authorization_endpoint,
        userinfo_endpoint: response.userinfo_endpoint,
        jwks_uri: response.jwks_uri,
        end_session_endpoint: response.end_session_endpoint
      };
      config['signingKeys'] = response.signingKeys;
      config['extraQueryParams'] = {
        resource: response.claimsApiResourceId
      };
      this._userManager = new UserManager(config);
      this._userManager.getUser().then(user => {
        if (user && !user.expired) {
          this._user = user;
          this.isLoggedInSubject$.next(user);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

The `AuthService` is pretty standard, all the important pieces for this question are in the constructor.

The component in question using this service is the following:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActionLink } from '../../shared/models/actionlink';
import { AuthService } from '../../core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'thrive-resources-card',
  templateUrl: './resources-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./resources-card.component.scss']
})
export class ResourcesCardComponent {

  @Input() public actionLinks: ActionLink[];

  public firstName$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    this.firstName$ = this.authService.isLoggedInSubject$.pipe(
      map(response => response.profile.unique_name.replace(/\s+/, '').split(',')[1])
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the test component for the `ResourceCardComponent` as well:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ResourcesCardComponent } from './resources-card.component';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { ActivatedRoute, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ResourcesCardContainerComponent } from './resources-card-container/resources-card-container.component';

const fakeRoute = {
  snapshot: {
      data: {
        actionLinks: []
      }
  }
};

describe('ResourcesCardComponent', () => {
  let component: ResourcesCardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ResourcesCardComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        ResourcesCardComponent,
        ResourcesCardContainerComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        RouterModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useFactory: () => fakeRoute
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ResourcesCardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    component.actionLinks = [];
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initiate your service with

```
public isLoggedInSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this._user)
```

because `this._user` is undefined.

Then in your component, your want `response.profile.unique_name.replace(/\s+/, '') ...`

**BUT** `this.authService.isLoggedInSubject$` return as first value `undefined`. This is why you have this error.

You should either mock you service to return an observable `of({profile:{unique_name:'some name'}})` Or initiate your user with better data.

```
spyOn(authService , 'isLoggedInSubject$').and.returnValue(of({profile:{unique_name:'some name'}}))
```

Comment: I am fully aware of this as the error, I'm trying to figure out how to potentially get around this error. Any ideas?